# How can i send packet to another node in HWMP?

Tags: tcl, ns2

I work on smart grid, NAN part (Neighborhood Area Network). And the default routing protocol for IEEE802.11s is HWMP. I use NS2 and HWMP patch for implementing a hybrid wireless mesh network (5*5 node).

Now I must send some packet from nodes to a aggregation node to send some data from every node to 1 aggregation node.

How can I generate and send this packet?

Comment: When you say NS2, do you mean the Lawrence Berkeley National Laboratory's [Network Simulator](http://nsnam.isi.edu/nsnam/index.php/Main_Page)?

Comment: OK. Your question was only tagged with "tcl" and didn't mention simulation at all, so it was hard to tell. I have tagged your question with [tag:ns2] to help people find it.